# Creating custom GraphQL schema for Drupal 9 empty fields which are paragraph references

Tags: drupal, graphql, gatsby

Have a decoupled Drupal 9 with Gatsby and a GraphQL. On Drupal's side there is a node called `school` there is a field (`field_components`) which is an Entity Reference Field which can have unlimited number of references to paragraphs. There are over 50 paragraph types on the site but that specific field only accept four (4) types. And I am trying to define their types in GraphQL.

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;
  const typeDefs = `
    type node__school implements Node {
      field_location: String
      field_type_r_a: Boolean
      relationships: node__schoolRelationships
    }
    
    type node__schoolRelationships {
      field_components: // this is where i need to define the 4 types 
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs);
};
```

As you can see by the example above I've written out 90% of the necessary schema but I have no idea how to define the for paragraph types. I'm guessing that each individual paragraph would be called `paragraph__machine_name` (e.g. **paragraph__carousel**) but since there are four (4) of them I don't know how to chain them (define them all)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the [GraphQL docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/):

> Unions and interfaces are abstract GraphQL types that enable a schema field to return one of multiple object types.

In action (using paragraph entities):

```js
  const typeDefs = `
    type node__school implements Node {
      field_location: String
      field_type_r_a: Boolean
      relationships: node__schoolRelationships
    }
    
    union fieldContentParagraphUnion =
      paragraph__foo
        | paragraph__bar
        | paragraph__bat

    type paragraph__foo implements Node {
      field_1: String
    }

    type paragraph__bar implements Node {
      field_2: String
    }

    type paragraph__bat implements Node {
      field_3: String
    }

    type node__schoolRelationships {
      field_components: [fieldContentParagraphUnion] @link(from: "field_components___NODE") 
    }
  `
```

This official Gatsby plugin helped me tame my schema-related issues: [gatsby-plugin-schema-snapshot](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-schema-snapshot/)

> Saves a minimal schema to file, adds the @dontInfer directive to all top-level types, and re-creates the schema from the saved type definitions during bootstrap. Use this plugin if you intend to lock-down a project’s GraphQL schema.